# COUNTIF function that combines an ARRAY and COLUMN

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have and Excel sheet that looks like this:

```
gender fruit1 fruit2
M      Apple  Orange 
M      Apple  Orange
F      Orange
F      Apple
F
```

I want to create a COUNTIF function that returns how many ocurrences of each fruit I have by Gender, so effectively combining counting in an array (fruit1 fruit2) and gender.

Expected results:

```
Apple Male = 2
Apple Female =1
Orange Male = 2
Orange Female =1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about how your desired results should look like?

Comment: What have you tried? countif() or even countifs() is very flexible.

Comment: Updated with expected results

Comment: as @SolarMike has pointed out, the `COUNTIFS()` function can help you there.
See instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842).

Comment: COUNTIFS (COL, CRITERIA, ARRAY, CRITERIA) does nos yield expected results, seems like it does not work when combining arrays and columns

Comment: Current formula looks like this:

=COUNTIFS(B1:C7,"apple",A1:A7,"male")

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(B1:B7,"apple",A1:A7,"M")+COUNTIFS(C1:C7,"apple",A1:A7,"M")`

Comment: Real life data has around Fruit1 to Fruit25 should I do this then for every column?

Comment: So I assume you have a cross-table already set up to house the results, for example with fruits across the top and gender down the side? If not, what set-up did you have in mind for you results?

Comment: Do you have a list of unique fruits to count against? unique() may help...

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:Z7="Apple")*(A2:A7="M"))`

Comment: @EGM8686 An important question that matters is this:  Within the 25 columns of fruit, is it (a) permissible for a fruit to appear more than once and (b) what do you want counted if a fruit *does* appear more than once.  Can the first person have `Apple, Apple, Orange` and if so, do you want your count to recognize 1 or 2?  In other words, are you counting pieces of fruit or counting the people who have at least one piece of that fruit.

Comment: @EGM8686 If you encounter this kind of multi-criteria requirement often, I would **highly** recommend investing the time to fully understand Spectral's `SUMPRODUCT` approach.  It takes a while to understand and practice it (and double unary ops), but it is absolutely a valuable Excel skill that is well worth the time.  With or without O365, it allows you to SUM, COUNT, and AVERAGE data sets with *any* combination of AND and OR criteria, and has almost none of the limitations of the various `xxxIFS()` functions.  It's one of those things that will change your excel life, and there are several.